# Width of Single Character of UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to find number of characters that can be displayed on single line of UILabel

I have width of single line

Comment: The number of characters that fits your width depends on the characters ... a "w" is much bigger than a "l". Without knowing the string, thats kinda impossible to tell.

Comment: you can add characters by one to label and check number of lines on each loop

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that, when we add "...see more " at the end of the UILabel. How we do it? What If I want to add it at the end of the 3rd line, only If the text exceeds the 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
func getWidthFor(title: String) -> CGFloat {
    let font = UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 13.0)
    let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
    let size = title.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any])
    return size.width
}
```

And then either send on character as a string, or send whole text and check if it fits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Find the number of characters that fits in a UITextView with constant width and height with a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083224/find-the-number-of-characters-that-fits-in-a-uitextview-with-constant-width-and)

```
func numberOfCharactersThatFitLabel() -> Int {

    // Create an 'CTFramesetterRef' from an attributed string
    let fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(font.fontName as CFString?, font.pointSize, nil)
    var attributes: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil
    if let fontRef = fontRef {
        attributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : fontRef]
    }
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
    let frameSetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString as CFAttributedString?)

    // Get a suggested character count that would fit the attributed string
    var characterFitRange: CFRange
    CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetterRef, CFRangeMake(0, 0), nil, CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(numberOfLines) * font.lineHeight), &characterFitRange)
    return Int(characterFitRange.length)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In objective-C you can estimate it not exactly, but there is a work around:
Get specific letter in string and determine letter size. Using UILabel frame width you can calculate average number of characters which can be displayed in single line.

```
NSString *letter = [label.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)];

CGSize letterSize = [letter sizeWithFont:self.font];

NSNumber* numberOfCharacters = UILabel.frame.Size.width / letterSize;
```

if it can help you. Also it will work accurate if you have used monospaced font.

Comment: I see nothing re: Objective-C in the question. Might want to re-format your code in Swift.